# Kolmogorov extension theorem compact subset

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Reading the proof of the Kolmogorov's extension theorem, there's a claim that is not clear at all to me

> Given $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ a borel set, for every $\varepsilon >0$ there is a compact subset $B\subset A$ such that $\mu(A\setminus B)\leq \varepsilon$.

I read a justification from [here](http://bass.math.uconn.edu/math5160f14/post9.pdf) but everything is as unclear as before.

Comment: The idea is it is possible to take a compact set that is different (in probability \mu) from the borel set A of a little quantity $\epsilon$. This result is important because you can work only with the compact sets of the space. It is a control result.

Comment: All the measures here are [regular measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_measure).

Comment: @kimchilover where can I find proof of the regularity of an arbitrary probability measure over the borelians of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Theorems 1.4.8 (for the $\mathbb R^n$ case) and 7.1.7 (more generally)  in Bogachev's _Measure Theory_, for instance.  The references to the Wikipedia article are fine, too.

Comment: You can also look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3672518/485385