When are absolutely continuous measures on $\Bbb R^d$ also Radon measures?
A measure $\mu$ is called Radon if it is inner-regular and locally finite. I will only consider measures on $\Bbb R^d$. Given a function $g\in L^1(\Bbb R^d)$, we can define $$d\mu(x) = g(x)\, dx,$$
which is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure. For which functions $g\in L^1(\Bbb R^d)$ is $\mu$ a Radon measure? It would be nice to know sufficient conditions.
In particular, here's what I am trying to do: Given a Radon measure $\nu$ on $\Bbb R^d$, and $f\in L^1(\Bbb R^d)$, consider the convolution $\nu \ast f$. We have $(\nu\ast f)(x) = \int f(x-y)\, d\nu(y)$, and
$$\int |(\nu\ast f)(x)|\, dx \le \int\int |f(x-y)|\, d\nu(y)\, dx = \int\int |f(x-y)|\, dx\, d\nu(y) = \nu(\Bbb R^d) \|f\|_1  < \infty,$$
if $\nu(\Bbb R^d) < \infty$ (assume this is the case). The swap of integrals is justified by Tonelli's theorem. Now, we have $\nu \ast f \in L^1(\Bbb R^d)$, which gives rise to an absolutely continuous measure $$d\mu(x) = (\nu \ast f)(x)\, dx.$$
Is $\mu$ Radon if $\nu$ is Radon? Do we need more conditions on $f$?
Thank you!

Every such measure $\mu$ is Radon. We can prove this directly without having to invoke general results.
Since $f \in L^1$, the measure $\mu$ is finite and in particular is locally finite.  It remains to show it is inner regular.
Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a Lebesgue measurable set, and suppose at first that $m(A) < \infty$.  By inner regularity of $A$, for each $n$ there exists a compact $K_n \subseteq A$ with $m(K_n) > m(A) - 1/n$, which is to say that $m(A \setminus K_n) < 1/n$.  We can assume without loss of generality that $K_1 \subseteq K_2 \subseteq \dots$.  By countable additivity, $m\left(A \setminus \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty K_n\right) = 0$.  Since $\mu$ is absolutely continuous, we have $\mu\left(A \setminus \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty K_n\right)=0$ as well.  But the countable additivity of $\mu$ then implies that $\mu(K_n) \to \mu(A)$, so $\mu$ is inner regular on $A$.
If instead $m(A) = \infty$, set $A_k = A \cap [-k,k]$.  By countable additivity, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $k$ with $\mu(A_k) > \mu(A) - \epsilon$.  By the previous case applied to $A_k$, there exists a compact $K \subset A_k$ with $\mu(K) > \mu(A_k) - \epsilon$.  We thus have $\mu(K) > \mu(A) - 2\epsilon$.

If $X$ is a locally compact, second countable Hausdorff space then the Borel measures on $\mathcal{B}(X)$ are regular and therefore all Borel measures on $\mathcal{B}(X)$ are Radon measures (regularity theorems).
Obviously $\mathbb{R}^d$ is a locally compact, second countable Hausdorff space. Further, for a measureable, non-negative function $g:\mathbb{R}^d\to [0,+\infty]$ the measure $\mu$ with $d\mu = g dx$ is a Borel measure if and only if $g \in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^d)$. So it suffices to choose $g \in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ with $g\geq 0$.

Thanks very much! Could you point me to references for these specific results?

@stoic-santiago: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3623555/reference-request-finite-borel-measure-are-radon for some references.
